# I want to display the element in an arraylist, not the hashcode

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently trying to display a csv file called "Haha2" using csv open in Java. Unfortunately when I print the arraylist I get the hashcode and not the numbers that are contained in the file.

I have tried the .get() method and the .toArray() and .toString methods but I am still only able to print out the hashcode.

Here's my code:

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class playlist{

   public static void main (String args()) throws IOException {

      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("Haha2.asc"),';', '"',29);

      List <String[]> data = new ArrayList <String[]>();
      data = reader.readAll();

      System.out.println(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to loop through all elements in `data` and then for each element you again have to loop for all elements in each `String[]`.

Comment: @Harry: You should make that an answer!

Comment: @Oli: there are already similar answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a **one-liner** which first converts the list to an array giving you an array-of-arrays and then calling [`Arrays.deepToString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Either loop through your list and call `Arrays.toString()` on each of the array of Strings, or transform `List<String[]>` into `List<List<String>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
for( String[] array : data ) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the `List` and than over the array:

```
for( String[] array : data ) {
    for( String string : array ) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    System.out.println("---");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String[] arr : data) {
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println("...");
}
```